# The Unknown Calculator

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

After you solved [the goblins' puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116994/find-out-our-numbers-liars-and-truth-tellers), you decided to go home. But the king of the goblins returned, now at your back door!

'You have outsmarted me, but NOT THIS TIME! I am gonna make you die, SAAAY GOODBYYYYE!!'

'No!!! I said, I'm a genius of brain teasers and logic puzzles!'

'I'll give you ONE LAST CHANCE TO LIVE.'

The goblin gives you a pocket calculator with strange symbols.

'What're these strange symbols on the buttons?'

'The white buttons on top are the functions and brackets +, -, *, /, (, ), $x^2$, $x^y$, sqrt, ln, $2^x$, $e^x$, sin, cos, tan, but I'm not telling you which is which. Trig functions work in radians. The $x^y$ button works like this. To calculate $b^p$, you press b, $x^y$ and p.

The black buttons on the bottom are our base-5 digits 0 through 4 (we have billions of number systems), radix point, unary minus and pi, but yet again, I'm not telling you which is which. The display will also be in these symbols.

The blue button is equals, which gives the answer to your math problem, and the red one clears what you typed.

If syntax and math errors occur, the screen will flash red and clear your text, but nothing else will happen.

You have to determine what each symbol means on the calculator in as few equals button presses as possible. No questions. Now type in your first problem.'

How many equals button presses do you need to determine which button is which?

(You could also give some tips on this question, not just answers)

Comment: Nice of him to give you another chance to live just because you said "no".

Comment: Do we have to Press PI & then SIN & then =,  to get some Display ? Or we have to Press SIN & PI & = ? Or Press PI to get some Display, even without = ? Or SIN & PI will Display the value without = ? [[ I am assuming I know (or found out) which is PI & SIN , I am asking out the "working method" of this calculator ]]

Comment: Press buttons like you do on a TI-84.

Comment: unfortunately I have no TI-84 :: I am asking **(1)** whether only "=" Button shows Display , or we get Display when-ever we press a Button ?? **(2)** whether "SIN" shows Display with or without "=" Button ?? **(3)** whether Parameter to "SIN" is given before or after "SIN" ?? **(4)** whether Display is updated at every Button Press or only with "=" Button ??

Comment: Echoing @Prem's comments, you need to explain how this calculator works. Particularly the x^y button. And do the trig functions work in degrees or radians?  Without this information, there could be several different answers to this that are perfectly valid.

Comment: Are you aware of a provably optimal solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because not many details were given to my comments, I am basing this answer on a lot of assumptions:

Press the black buttons, checking the display. When you see a small symbol, mark the button with X. When you see the display change drastically, that button must be PI. Use the symbols in PI to match with the other DIGITS & POINT. The last black button must be "-".

No "=" pressed till now.

Now, press PI & a white button & "=". If the display changes to PI^2, you got the "^2" Button. Else, clear it and try next white button. This way, you can easily find the ^2 Button, with a maximum of 15 "=" presses.

Now, press PI & a white button & PI & "=".

- If the display changes to 0, you got the "SUB" button.
- If the display changes to 1, you got the "DIV" button.
- If the display changes to 2PI, you got the "ADD" button.
- If the display changes to PI^2, you got the "MUL" button.
- If the display changes to PI^PI, you got the "X^Y" button.
- Else, clear it and try the next white button. This takes a maximum of 14 "=" presses.

Now, press a white button & PI & "=".

- If the display changes to 0, you got the "SIN" button.
- If the display changes to -1, you got the "COS" button.
- If the display changes to small number, you got the "SQRT" button.
- If the display changes to very small number, you got the "ln" button.
- If the display changes to E^PI, you got the "E^Y" button.
- Else, clear it and try the next white button. This takes a maximum of 9 "=" presses.

Only 3 white buttons remain.
Press a white button & 0 =. If the display changes to 0, you got "tan"
This takes a maximum of 3 "=" presses.

Only 2 white buttons remain.
Press "W1 1 + 2 W2 =". If the display changes to 3, you got W1="(" & W2+")"
Else press "W2 1 + 2 W1 =". If  the display changes to 3, you got W2="(" & W1+")"

Once more, I will pause here, waiting for OP to comment whether this is what he is looking for!

Comment: No, because the display will also be in these strange symbols so when you type 1 it won’t show 1 it will show something like ➰.

Comment: Ok , got it ; It will be "Possible" , but too laborious !! I suggest you make it Base 4 & eliminate some operations !!